# How to select records by time regardless of date

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for my English. I apologize for the last post (I didn't know it's not okay to post images).

i have a datetime column in my database.

```
start
     2021-06-28 08:30:00
     2021-06-29 08:00:00
     2021-06-30 08:00:00
```

I need to select by time. Regardless of the day. I need to select all records with a time equal to 8:00.

that is, I should bring the results:

```
2021-06-29 08:00:00
2021-06-30 08:00:00
```

I tried using the clause HOUR(start) ='08:00', but it doesn't solve it, because it works with integer. Does anyone know how I can do this query?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html

Comment: @astentx that's right. thank you very much, friend. I didn't know how to look for the correct words.

Comment: @astentx a doubt, friend. when I create a duplicate topic, should I delete it?

Comment: There's no rule for this, as far as I know. So you are free to leave it as is, edit it and add more clarification to make the question not a duplicate or delete the question if you think it is not worth to stay on SO search results and it has not much new context compared to original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@astentx is referencing a post with the right solution. Specifically your looking for:

```
WHERE TIME(`start`) = '08:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                        
indata(ts) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-06-28 08:30:00'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-06-29 08:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-06-30 08:00:00'
)
SELECT * FROM indata WHERE CAST(ts AS TIME)='08:00:00';

-- out          ts          
-- out ---------------------
-- out  2021-06-29 08:00:00
-- out  2021-06-30 08:00:00
```